# How to use ggrepel with a survival plot (ggsurvplot)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel, survminer

I would like to add the label of each survival curve at the end of the lines.
I am using `ggsurvplot` from the `Survminer` package (which is based on `ggplot2`).
I don't know how to do it with `ggrepel`. I didn't find any example with survival data:

```
require("survival")
library(survminer)
library(ggrepel)
fit<- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
p=ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung)$plot; 
p + geom_label_repel()
```

The code above throws an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object `p` you have created contains enough information to generate the labels. `p$data` is a data frame, and contains a column called `strata` which you can use here. You need to map the `label` aesthetic to this column. You will also need to filter a copy of the data to pass to the `geom_label_repel` layer that contains only the maximum `time` value for each stratum:

```r
p + geom_label_repel(aes(label = strata),
                     data = p$data %>% 
                            group_by(strata) %>%
                            filter(time == max(time)))
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to put sex=1 and sex = 2 really at the end of the line?

Comment: @TarJae yes - I think using plain old `geom_label` with an hjust of 0 would do that.